# How to use a controller inside a folder in the controllers folder with Play framework 1.4.3

Tags: java, html, playframework

I'm working with Play framework 1.4.3 and my problem is that  i created a new folder inside in the controllers folder and in this new folder added new controllers class and I did the same with a folder of the views but when in my html , i tried to declared in the href of a tag ancla the route ,  this not it  found my controller created, only found the controller for default "Application.java".

Example:

[image]

This is my folder hierarchy

[image]

I can use a controller inside a folder in the controllers folder with Play Framework 1.4.3?

This is my MyServicesControlle:

```
package controllers.myServices;

import play.mvc.Controller;

public class MyServicesController extends Controller {

    public static void index() {
       render();
    }
}
```

when i write the whole path in a tag ancla:

```
 <a href="@{app.controllers.myServices.MyServicesController.index}">my   services</a>
```

throws this exception:

```
 19:11:34,868 ERROR ~ 

 @73mb1o6aa
 Internal Server Error (500) for request GET /application/index

 Oops: PatternSyntaxException
 An unexpected error occured caused by exception PatternSyntaxException: group redeclaration controller; use ({=name}...) for group reassignments

 play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error
  at play.Invoker$Invocation.onException(Invoker.java:245)
  at play.Invoker$Invocation.run(Invoker.java:307)
  at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
 Caused by: jregex.PatternSyntaxException: group redeclaration controller; use ({=name}...) for group reassignments
  at jregex.Term.makeTree(jregex/Term.java:299)
  at jregex.Term.makeTree(jregex/Term.java:219)
  at jregex.Term.makeTree(jregex/Term.java:206)
  at jregex.Pattern.compile(jregex/Pattern.java:164)
  at jregex.Pattern.<init>(jregex/Pattern.java:150)
  at jregex.Pattern.<init>(jregex/Pattern.java:108)
  at play.mvc.Router$Route.compute(Router.java:828)
  at play.mvc.Router.getRoute(Router.java:142)
  at play.mvc.Router.appendRoute(Router.java:126)
  at play.mvc.Router.parse(Router.java:208)
  at play.mvc.Router.parse(Router.java:173)
  at play.mvc.Router.load(Router.java:53)
  at play.mvc.Router.detectChanges(Router.java:232)
  ... 1 more
```

Comment: Can you show us the `MyServicesController.java` class declaration?

Comment: Have you tried to type the whole path? Like `app.controllers.myServices.MyServicesController`

Comment: I tried to type the whole path and throw PatternSyntaxException

Comment: I worked with  <a href="@{myServices.MyServicesController.index}">my   services</a>, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first it was necessary to reference the folder where the controller was located, followed by the name of the controller and then the action.

Following the previous example:

```
<a href="@{myServices.MyServicesController.index}">my services</a>
```